# Applozic not synchronized users - Android

Tags: android, applozic

I create a new user but he is not synchronized to the chat contact immediately. If I log out and log in again I am able to see the added user. How can I fix it that?

Comment: Where it is not synchronized  is it in Contact list screen  ?Or  its ConversationActivity where you will see all the users/groups chats ?

Comment: In the contact list when I want to choose a user to chat with. The user is saved in the database I can find it in the dashboard just dont get them in the app.

Comment: in applozic-settings.json file did you made flag  "registeredUserContactListCall": true,  to true?

Comment: Yes, I made the flag to true.

Comment: once you scroll down in that contact list it will load other new contacts

Comment: in my case it doesnt. I see I unterstood wrongly it doesn't return the current user either. The amount without the user machtes. Thanks